# how to print 2d array in php from database values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to print an 2d array like this from values fetched from database having table 'product' whose structure is like this

```
name   product_name   rating 
rahul  fifa 15         3
rahul  gta 5           4
bidur  GOD OF WAR     3.5
bidur  gta 5          4
```

I wan't output like below using php/mysql

```
$books = array(

"rahul" => array("fifa 15" => 3,"gta 5" => 4),

"bidur" => array("GOD OF WAR" => 3.5,"gta 5" => 4),

"sushil" => array("HEAVY RAIN" => 4),

"vivek" => array("FIFA 15" => 3,"gta 5" => 4),

"anup" => array("Read Dead Redemption" => 4.5),

"nikhil" => array("FAR CRY 4" => 4.5,"HEAVY RAIN" => 3),

"akhi" => array("WWE RAW" => 3.5)

);
```

i have tried this 
i am using php/mysql  I wan't to get table data into a 2d array and i have tried like this

```
$books=array();

$sql="select distinct(email) from product_order";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die($con->error);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $email=$row['email'];
    $query="select product_name,rating from product_order where email='$email'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die($con->error);


    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $books["$email"][]=$r["product_name"];
        $books["$email"][]=$r["rating"];
    }

}


if($result) echo 'success';
else 'failure';

print_r($books);
```

but it is not working

Comment: So you are trying to fetch some data from your db and structure the array like that?

Comment: where is the code you've tried on ?

Comment: You would need to write some significant formatting code... or find someone who has already done that. Afaik, there is no way in core PHP to do this in any simple terms.

Comment: in my database  i have a table called product having structure describe above

Comment: Select data from your table, iterate over it and fill an array.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood the question. Perhaps rephrase it to "How do I get table data into a 2d array". Add what you've tried already, and information about what type of database you're using, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want `product_name` field be a key and `rating` field be a value:

```
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $books["$email"][$r["product_name"]]=$r["rating"];
}
```